# metalsmith config to read only markdown files

Tags: metalsmith

I have a (deeply nested) `./src` directory with a mix of various files, including some `*.md` files.

I want Metalsmith to recursively find ONLY the markdown files.

But at the moment the different configs I’ve tried copies ALL files into the static site, or none.

This is what I have at the moment:

```json
{
    "source": "./src",
    "destination": "static-site",
    "clean": true,
    "metadata": {
      "sitename": "My Static Site & Blog",
      "siteurl": "https://example.com/",
      "description": "It's about saying »Hello« to the world.",
      "generatorname": "Metalsmith",
      "generatorurl": "https://metalsmith.io/"
    },
    "plugins": [
      { "@metalsmith/collections": { "posts": "*.md" } },
      { "@metalsmith/drafts": true },
      { "@metalsmith/markdown": true },
      { "@metalsmith/permalinks": "posts/:title" }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, what is in your `metalsmith.source()` is intended to be copied & processed in full (else you wouldn't put it in `metalsmith.source()`).

If you want metalsmith to completely ignore some files you can use `metalsmith.ignore()`. If you want to use those files, but discard them from the build output, you can use [@metalsmith/remove](https://github.com/metalsmith/remove). You can specify a negated glob to remove/ignore all files *but* markdown: `!**/*.md`. [See it in action](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=false&glob=%21%2A%2A%2F%2A.md&matches=false&options=dot%3Atrue&tests=posts%2Findex.md&tests=some-script.js&tests=services%2Findex.md&tests=index.md&tests=my-first-post.md&tests=.env)

Mind you that the pattern `*.md` will only match markdown files at the root of the source, if you want to match all markdown files in subfolders too, you should specify `**/*.md`. [See it in action](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=false&glob=%2A%2A%2F%2A.md&matches=false&options=dot%3Atrue&tests=posts%2Findex.md&tests=services%2Findex.md&tests=index.md&tests=my-first-post.md)

With that, your config becomes:

```json
{
    "source": "./src",
    "destination": "static-site",
    "clean": true,
    "ignore": ["!**/*.md"],
    "metadata": {
      "sitename": "My Static Site & Blog",
      "siteurl": "https://example.com/",
      "description": "It's about saying »Hello« to the world.",
      "generatorname": "Metalsmith",
      "generatorurl": "https://metalsmith.io/"
    },
    "plugins": [
      { "@metalsmith/collections": { "posts": "**/*.md" } },
      { "@metalsmith/drafts": true },
      { "@metalsmith/markdown": true },
      { "@metalsmith/permalinks": {
          "relative": false,
          "pattern": "posts/:title"
      }
    ]
  }
```

PS: it is highly likely that you want `@metalsmith/permalinks` ' relative option to be false.